# Injection not working with imported beans in vaadin

Tags: vaadin7

I am new to vaadin I came from GWT based project where we have persistence and business logic as Java EE modules and web client as Java Web app. Now I have my modules ready with my app logic intact the only problem I am having now is how to inject my beans to vaadin app because using the vaadin cdi addon, I can only inject classes from the vaadin app. Is there a way I can inject my classes? I added the classes to my vaadin app as  dependencies. Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, but there are some issues, especially with some environments. Makes sure you use the latest Vaadin CDI release. With the current 1.0.2 there are this kind of issues with some servers, but the workaround is to upgrade the project to use explicitly DeltaSpike 1.2.1. I a helper project that does this and adds also some handy helper libraries called vaadin-java-ee-essentials. If you don't want to start using it, check its [pom.xml](https://github.com/mstahv/vaadin-java-ee-essentials/blob/master/pom.xml) how Deltapike version can be upgraded. [An example](https://github.com/mstahv/jpa-invoicer) that uses it.

If you can't make it work, let me know more about your server and setup so we can fix it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I upgraded the DeltaSpike to 1.2.1 but its still not working. I am using glassfish 4.0 and Netbeans 8. I browse the example project your provided what i want to know is how did u structure the code because I am using three different projects i.e persistence and business logic as Java EE projects and Vaadin app as the client. Should i just use the vaadin app only and transfer the persistence layer into it?

Comment: Can you still check with Glassfish 4.1? IIRC 4.1 fixed some Vaadin CDI -Glassfish incompatibility. Separate modules shouldn't be an issues, but there has been some issues and I think there still is some with ear packaging and DeltaSpike(on which Vaadin CDI depends) and some containers.